# Require loads a module even though it's included in the build

Tags: debugging, requirejs, dependency-management, duplicates

I'm working on a fairly complex Require project; at the core of this project is a third-party video player code base that we're building an app around.  I'm currently working out our production build process, using the Require optimizer.

The optimizer works great, but when I use the app with the "built" JS, Require insists on loading the third-party module by inserting an additional script tag.  I've searched through the compiled JS and confirmed the module was included in the build; yet it doesn't seem to be recognized at runtime.

This module is what requires the third-party module:

```
define(['models/Widget','amp_lib'], function(Widget) {
    // Housekeeping/configuration
    // Nothing to return here
})
```

The module amp_lib is defined in the main config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        amp_lib: 'path/to/module/src'
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me understand how Require determines whether a particular module has been loaded or not?  I've been poking around in Require itself all day long, hoping to find out where this determination is made, to no avail.

Comment: Is this only with third party module? Does third party module return value? Also, are you sure it is not referenced somewhere else using different path? e.g.: 'module/amp_lib'. Can you share demo?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really share a demo...however, here's some additional info: The content of that third-party module makes a difference. If I replace the contents with something like: 

'(function(){ return null; }());' 

then Require does not reload the module. I think what I'll do is float this to the third-party developers; they're in our office this week to coordinate on this project. Initially I'd thought it had nothing to do with them, but now I'm wondering if maybe we can figure out what part of their (rather large) codebase may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: UPDATE: I found the problem today. Turns out the third-party module we get is using a few utility libraries, one of which is AMD-compliant and thus has its own define() function when it detects a loader. So when building, the optimizer was defining just that library as the module, instead of the entire codebase, which in turn caused the module to be reloaded at runtime.

Lesson learned: be careful with stuffing third-party stuff into a Require project.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> I found the problem today. Turns out the third-party module we get is using a few utility libraries, one of which is AMD-compliant and thus has its own define() function when it detects a loader. So when building, the optimizer was defining just that library as the module, instead of the entire codebase, which in turn caused the module to be reloaded at runtime. Lesson learned: be careful with stuffing third-party stuff into a Require project.